# Error when calling DocuSign's get access token API on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, docusignapi, docusignconnect, docusign-sdk

**I get error:**

```
{
     "error": "invalid_request",
     "error_description": "code challenge and code challenge method required"
}
```

What do I need to do to fix this error?

I followed Docusign's instructions but the error still appears

Comment: Please don't change the topic of the question. If you want to post a new question about a different error, create a new post.

Answer (score 1):

That error is highlighting that you possibly have pcke enabled on your integration & not passing through a code

https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/authcode/authcode-get-token/#optional-pkce-code-challenge

More information available here: https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/docusign-adds-support-pkce